# wx.gauge incrementing in steps, not smooth [linux, python3]

Tags: wxpython

I am incrementing a wx.gauge object from a for loop that collects url addresses. In debug mode it works perfectly. As soon as I run it in real time it only updates in approximately 15% chunks. I've tested with toy script and it also works perfectly. Given that it works fine as I step through the program in debug, and a toy script works fine, I can't even figure out example code to post. But I'm hoping someone else may have experienced the same issue and can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Without code anyone answering would be guessing and what is a `toy script`?

Comment: Embarrassing solution was to slow the loop down with time.sleep(.02). It was looping so fast that wx.gauge only had the opportunity to update at the 50 url batch limit that I'm guessing reddit imposes. For future reference.